# LinkAssemblies error when Release Mode in xamarin

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, telerik

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       The "LinkAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly.
Xamarin.Android.XamarinAndroidException: error XA2006: Reference to metadata item 'System.Boolean Android.Support.V7.Widget.RecyclerView/ItemAnimator::AnimateAdd(Android.Support.V7.Widget.RecyclerView/ViewHolder)' (defined in 'Telerik.Xamarin.Android.List, Version=2016.1.324.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null') from 'Telerik.Xamarin.Android.List, Version=2016.1.324.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' could not be resolved. ---> Mono.Cecil.ResolutionException: Failed to resolve System.Boolean Android.Support.V7.Widget.RecyclerView/ItemAnimator::AnimateAdd(Android.Support.V7.Widget.RecyclerView/ViewHolder)
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethod(MethodReference reference)
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkInstruction(Instruction instruction)
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethodBody(MethodBody body)
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessMethod(MethodDefinition method)
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process()
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)
at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process(LinkContext context)
at MonoDroid.Tuner.Linker.Process(LinkerOptions options, LinkContext& context)
at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute()
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Xamarin.Android.Diagnostic.Error(Int32 code, Exception innerException, String message, Object[] args)
at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute()
at  Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext()
```

When i build the releasing mode My App giving this error can you please Help me how can i resoleve this

Comment: Try to select option Link sdk assemblies only

Comment: i didn't get you, where can i find this option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could find that in options of the project

some what like this Change Linker behavior to Link SDK assemblies only

[image]

This might solve not sure try

Comment: Linker Option not showing in android project Properties.